# “reinstall” or “re-install”

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, difference

> You have to reinstall/re-install the program.
>
> You have to leave this box unchecked/un-checked.

Should I use *reinstall/unchecked* or *re-install/un-checked*?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It was [never at all common](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=unchecked,un-checked&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1;,unchecked;,c0;.t1;,un%20-%20checked;,c0) to hyphenate ***unchecked***. A few decades ago maybe [a quarter of all instances](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=reinstall,re-install&year_start=1900&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1;,reinstall;,c0;.t1;,re%20-%20install;,c0) of ***reinstall*** were hyphenated, but hardly anyone bothers any more.

The general tendency is for hyphens to gradually disappear in contexts where they're not actually necessary to disambiguate or enhance legibility. For those still soldiering on with MS Windows today, *reinstallation* is such a familiar word they don't need a hyphen to easily recognise the root component.

Comment: Funny!  And for the low price of $200, they'll walk you through the process over the phone.